# Windows to Android file transfer -- aborts after a minute or two

Tags: windows, android

I have a Win11 Dell Laptop and a recent (last 12 months) Sony Xperia Android phone.

I connect them via a USB-C to USB-C cable and select File transfer on the phone.

I use Windows Explorer to do the copy operation.

I try to copy, say, 1GB of music files. It runs for a few minutes and terminates with no message. I cut it to half a gig. Same thing. Quarter gig, same thing.

I have about 200GB to transfer.

The destination of the transfer is the SD card in the phone.

What is suggested?

Addition:
If I make the copy in really small chunks, and keep playing with the phone so it does not sleep, it appears the copy completes.

In the phone settings, I do not see a way to prevent it sleeping.

What to do?

Comment: Is the music stored on a micro SD card? They tend to get bad sectors easily. Anyway try to copy the files from command line so you see which file it is it fails. Perhaps it always fails at the same file. If this is not possible on Windows then switch to Linux (e.g. Ubuntu live stick or Ubuntu VM).

Comment: AFAIR file mode is stopped when the phone is locked. This is for security reasons. For reliable file copy even with locked phone enable developer options and adb. Then use command like adb client from Android SDK on PC side to push files to the phone.

Comment: As @Robert states, once the phone locks, transfer stops. If there is a µSD card in the phone, put the files on the card, pop it ou and put it in a card reader on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the Android phone going to sleep.

The solution is to turn on Developer Mode, and then there is a Developer option to keep the phone awake while it is charging (and when it is plugged in via USB for data transfer, it is also charging).

Just remember to turn the option off (or your screen stays on forever when you are just charging).

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was having restricted characters in the file name, and replacing them solved the issue.

For Android the restricted characters can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679699/what-characters-allowed-in-file-names-on-android)
It includes `?` and `"`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).